# Ejabberd virtual host announcement nickname

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

When I send announcement to users in ejabberd (using for example "Send announcement to all users on all hosts"), recipients see it as a message from virtual host with "ejabberd" nickname, which is unclear to users.

I wonder how to change this "ejabberd" nickname to something more convenient?

Very weird that there is absolutely no information about this in documentation and even no questions about this from somebody else. How it's possible that nobody cares about this? Maybe there is something wrong with my ejabberd configuration and virtual host shouldn't have "ejabberd" nickname by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this option:

```
  mod_disco:
    name: "ejabberd server"
```

Regarding the server vcard, try a patch like this:

```
--- a/src/mod_vcard.erl
+++ b/src/mod_vcard.erl
@@ -197,7 +197,7 @@ process_local_iq(#iq{type = set, lang = Lang} = IQ) ->
     xmpp:make_error(IQ, xmpp:err_not_allowed(Txt, Lang));
 process_local_iq(#iq{type = get, lang = Lang} = IQ) ->
     xmpp:make_iq_result(
-      IQ, #vcard_temp{fn = <<"ejabberd">>,
+      IQ, #vcard_temp{fn = <<"ejabberd server nickname">>,
                      url = ejabberd_config:get_uri(),
                      desc = misc:get_descr(Lang, ?T("Erlang Jabber Server")),
                      bday = <<"2002-11-16">>}).
```

Answer (score 1):

In my test, users receive the message with the vhost as sender address:

```
<message to='user1@localhost/tka1'
    from='localhost'
    type='headline'>
  <body xml:lang='en'>Hi

This is the content.

The localhost admins.</body>
  <subject xml:lang='en'>This is the subject</subject>
</message>
```

I see no example in the protocol about how it should look: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html#announce

Comment: Yes, sender is a vhost address, it's correct. But XMPP clients (at least some of them) are requesting sender nickname to display it instead of JID and ejabberd replies that vhost has nickname "ejabberd":

`<iq xml:lang="en" to="admin@localhost/LOCATION" from="localhost" type="result" id="mir_315">
<query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
<identity type="pep" category="pubsub" />
<identity name="ejabberd" type="im" category="server" />`

Comment: `<iq xml:lang="en" to="admin@localhost/LOCATION" from="localhost" type="result" id="mir_357">
<vCard xmlns="vcard-temp">
<FN>ejabberd</FN>
<URL>http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/</URL>
<BDAY>2002-11-16</BDAY>
<DESC>Erlang Jabber ServerCopyright (c) ProcessOne</DESC>
</vCard>
</iq>
`